# Qiime2 conda environment changing the name

Tags: conda

I had install qiime2 within a conda environment, but I forget to change the name of the environment, I copied the name of the example in the qiime2 guide. I would like to know if it's possible to change it now, or if I've to uninstall the qiime2 environment and install it again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Qiime2 official forum will be more helpful for you
https://forum.qiime2.org